# Tkinter Entry box skip rows

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, grid, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to create 6 rows of file dialogs using Tkinter lib and grid method, my code is as follow:

```
for roww in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]:
    ttk.Label(frm, text="Plot " + str(roww) +"   ").grid(column=0, row=roww) # Labels, all column 0
    ttk.Button(frm, text="Choose a .csv file", command=select_file).grid(column=1, row=roww) # Filedialog, all column 1
    ttk.Entry(root).grid(column=3, row=roww)
```

Which result in this:
[Tkinter Entry box skip rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99fcc.png)

How can I fix this and put the textboxs to where they should be?

Answer (score 1):

Update: I fixed by replacing "root" with frm, I misstyped the parent class.